# OpenShift mysql connection issues in python

Tags: python, mysql, openshift

I previously wrote my app using local development servers, and now that I have moved it onto an openshift small gear almost all works except for mysql connections.

In my code I have the line:

```
self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host, username, password, dbname)
```

When I review the openshift error log, the following error is reported:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

I think that python is trying to connect using a UNIX socket as opposed to an INET one, but I'm not sure how to change this behavior.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to MySQLdb: if you use `localhost` as hostname, a MySQL client using the MySQL C libraries will try to connect using UNIX socket (or named pipe on Windows). There are 2 ways around this, but you'll need to grant extra permissions to make it work for both:

### Use IP address 127.0.0.1

Use IP address 127.0.0.1 instead of the localhost hostname. This will make MySQL client connect using TCP/IP.

### Use option files

The other way is to force the protocol using using option files. For example, in your `~/.my.cnf` (or any file you want), add the following:

```
[python]
protocol=tcp
```

Now use the connection arguments to read the option file and group:

```
import MySQLdb
cnx = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='scott', passwd='tiger',
                      read_default_file='~/.my.cnf',
                      read_default_group='python')
```

The group name does not need to be `python`, but it is good not to use `mysql` or `client` as it might interfere with other MySQL tools (unless you want that of course).

For setting up permissions, you'll need to use the IP address of localhost, something like:

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT TO yourdb.* TO 'scott'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY ...;
```

(Site note: MySQL database drivers such as MySQL Connector/Python do not consider `localhost` to be special and connect through TCP/IP right away and you have to explicitly use the `unix_socket`.)

Answer (score 0):

As I later discovered, while the database server runs on localhost, it runs on a very specific localhost bind address.  In my case it was an address that I would never have though to try if I hadn't noticed how phpmyadmin was connecting.